# asp.net mvc2 model binding enumerable properties

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

```
public class ModelClass
{
    private List<ItemClass> _itemList = new ...
    public IList<ItemClass> ItemList
    {
        get
        {
            return _itemList;
        }
    }
}

public class ItemClass
{
    public string Property1 { get; set; }
}
```

I Can't get ModelClass to bind to a ViewPage with a for loop. Something like

```
<% for( int a = 0; a <=3; a++) { %>
<%= Html.TextBoxFor(b => b.ItemList[a].Property1) %>
<% } %>
```

Does MVC2 not allow model binding of enumerable properties?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I am currently manually binding that enumerable property in the controller, which isn't ideal :/, but is a work around (with deadline looming... )

Answer (score 0):

Based on your question, I'm not entirely sure what the problem is that you are having (compiler error? posting error? etc). The code looks like it should be OK except for the naming issues that you will probably have. I would suggest just writing out the textboxes manually.

```
<% for( int a = 0; a <=3; a++) { %>
<input type="text" name="Property1_<%=a%>" value="<%:Model.ItemList[a].Property1%>" />
<% } %>
```

Comment: My problem is that my the model object I receive in the controller isn't populated with the values in the IEnumerable. Funny thing is it displays the enumerable, but doesn't populate it on the postback.